# Google's Tag Manager adding ```jsx to my site, what's this tag for?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

We are getting an unwanted text in the footer, and I traced it to Google's GTM script.

https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-5BP9X2&gtm_auth=gTyBldj8fIR5vXs-aeCVgw&gtm_preview=env-2059&gtm_cookies_win=x

Is this an error in Google's script? Is in an error in my website? That is the only html template that starts with ```jsx so it is weird.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Odds are it is an error in how you configured GTM

Comment: Probably that JSX appears inside a GTM custom html tag that you/someone has added to your GTM container.

Comment: @James yes that was it, I am not in charge of DTM so couldn't check that, but yes it was our problem.